# NDepend - Baseline Coverage by Assembly Query

Tags: code-coverage, ndepend

is it possible to have a comparison by assembly to the baseline build?
At the moment I have a report that shows the coverage by assembly, but I would like to add the coverage compared to the baseline build for each assembly as well side by side.
How would a query look like?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with such [CQLinq code query](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/cqlinq-syntax):

```
from a in Application.Assemblies

select new { a, a.PercentageCoverage,
olderCov = a.OlderVersion() == null ? -1 : 
           a.OlderVersion().PercentageCoverage,
diffCov = a.OlderVersion() == null ? -1 : 
          a.PercentageCoverage - a.OlderVersion().PercentageCoverage
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the result:
[image: NDepend assembly code coverage compared]

Several points:

- The query can be easily rewritten to show diff of other coverage metrics like `a.NbLinesOfCodeCovered` for example
- This query can be easily transformed into a rule for example if any coverage ratio is decreasing ([related doc](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/cqlinq-syntax#Rule))
- Or if you prefer it not to be a rule but still gets this query result in [the report](https://www.ndepend.com/sample-reports/), just use [this feature (List code queries of this group in the report)](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/customize-ndepend-report#CQLQuery)